# Splitting annual data into quarters in pyspark df

Tags: pyspark

I have a df that looks like below. I need to break down annual data into quarters, so for each company for each year create a new row with quarter date and new EV (simply divide annual value by 4). Any suggestions how to do it?

```
+----------+------+---+
|      date|entity| EV|
+----------+------+---+
|2018-12-31|     x| 40|
|2019-12-31|     x| 80|
|2018-12-31|     y|120|
+----------+------+---+
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+------+---+
|      date|entity| EV|
+----------+------+---+
|2018-03-31|     x| 10|
|2018-06-30|     x| 10|
|2018-09-30|     x| 10|
|2018-12-31|     x| 10|
|2019-03-31|     x| 20|
|2019-06-30|     x| 20|
|2019-09-30|     x| 20|
|2019-12-31|     x| 20|
|2018-03-31|     y| 30|
|2018-06-30|     y| 30|
|2018-09-30|     y| 30|
|2018-12-31|     y| 30|
+----------+------+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using arrays and [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform).

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('qtr_dt_suffix', 
               func.array(func.lit('03-31'), func.lit('06-30'), func.lit('09-30'), func.lit('12-31'))
               ). \
    withColumn('qtr_dts', 
               func.transform('qtr_dt_suffix', lambda x: func.concat(func.year('dt'), func.lit('-'), x).cast('date'))
               ). \
    select(func.explode('qtr_dts').alias('qtr_dt'), 'entity', (func.col('ev') / 4).alias('ev')). \
    show()

# +----------+------+----+
# |qtr_dt    |entity|ev  |
# +----------+------+----+
# |2018-03-31|x     |10.0|
# |2018-06-30|x     |10.0|
# |2018-09-30|x     |10.0|
# |2018-12-31|x     |10.0|
# |2019-03-31|x     |20.0|
# |2019-06-30|x     |20.0|
# |2019-09-30|x     |20.0|
# |2019-12-31|x     |20.0|
# |2018-03-31|y     |30.0|
# |2018-06-30|y     |30.0|
# |2018-09-30|y     |30.0|
# |2018-12-31|y     |30.0|
# +----------+------+----+
```

Idea is to create an array containing all the quarter ending months and their end dates - `[03-31, 06-30, 09-30, 12-31]`. Use `transform` on this array to create dates for that year - `[2018-03-31, 2018-06-30, 2018-09-30, 2018-12-31]`. Explode this resulting array to create rows for each quarter dates.

---

If [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform) is not available in your spark version, you can use `transform` in `expr`.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('qtr_dt_suffix', 
               func.array(func.lit('03-31'), func.lit('06-30'), func.lit('09-30'), func.lit('12-31'))
               ). \
    withColumn('qtr_dts', 
               func.expr('transform(qtr_dt_suffix, x -> cast(concat(year(dt), "-", x) as date))')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: wow this is a great answer thank you! It turned out my original df contains companies that report not only at year end (yyyy-12-31) but also other quarters (yyyy-03-31, yyyy-06-30, yyyy-09-30). In that case I need create the quarter end array based on input date to look 4 quarters back. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: there are many ways to look back 4 quarters. would be good to have this as a new question with your original data format and a description of what you're trying to achieve.